# Words for "to encourage": alentar, animar, fomentar

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, sinónimos, vocabulario

In English, "to encourage" seems to have at least two uses:

1. to suggest that someone should do something (e.g. "He encouraged me to find a new guitar teacher.")
2. to give confidence or hope to someone (e.g. "In a rough time of life, he was always there to encourage me when I was feeling down." or "It's really encouraging to see how you've grown over the past year.")

How can these senses be translated to Spanish? As far as I know, there are at least three words in Spanish: *alentar*, *animar*, and *fomentar*. What is the difference between them?

Also, what about the noun form (encouragement) or the adjective form (encouraging)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[alentar](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=alentar).**
>
> Animar, infundir aliento o esfuerzo, dar vigor.

i.e. *To encourage* (*animar*), to give life or to give energy.

> **[animar](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=animar).**
>
> Incitar a alguien a una acción.

i.e. *To encourage* somebody to do something.

> **[fomentar](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=fomentar).**
>
> Excitar, promover, impulsar o proteger algo.

i.e. To excite, to *encourage*, to boost or to protect something.

So, *animar* and *alentar* are synonims when both means *encourage*.

In general, *animar* is more used in terms of *encourage*. I use *alentar* when trying to encourage someone who is dealing with a depression of some kind.
As for *fomentar*, I've never used as *to encourage* someone , but *to promote* something.

These are the most used forms:

- Noun. *encouragement* -> *ánimo* (from *animar*)
- Adj. *encouraging* -> *alentador* (from *alentar*)